# Nested if statement in pine script

Tags: if-statement, nested, pine-script

I'm trying to build a ema script in trading view but struggling with how to finish up the code. I'm essentially trying to code this, but not sure how to nest this in an if statement:

`(tl <= em1 and tc > ema2) and ((tc<ema3) or (tc<em4) or (tc<em5))`

How can I put a nested if statement for this? Goal is to use the if statement to tie in the rest of the code

````
// EMA trap
m1=8
m2=3.1
m3=3.2
m4=3.4

tl=low
tc=close

em1 = ema(tl,m1)
em2 = ema(tc,m1)
em3 = ema(tc,m2)
em4 = ema(tc,m3)
em5 = ema(tc,m4)```
````

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question and the purpose of your code snippet is unclear. Need to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use float periods for [`ema()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_ema), so replaced them with integers.

This plots an arrow on the chart when your condition is true:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
// EMA trap
m1=8
m2=3
m3=4
m4=5

tl=low
tc=close

em1 = ema(tl,m1)
em2 = ema(tc,m1)
em3 = ema(tc,m2)
em4 = ema(tc,m3)
em5 = ema(tc,m4)

cond = tl <= em1 and tc > em2 and (tc < em3 or tc < em4 or tc < em5)
plotchar(cond, "cond", "▼", location.top)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello,

Thank you so much for offering to help. So I think you're in the right path, but I think I haven't really explained what I'm trying to do and I apologize for that. What I'm attempting to code is this:

(Price for current bar's low cross below or equal to 8EMA, but closing above 8EMA) and ((Price for current bar's close lower than 3EMA 1 bar ago) or (Price for current bar's close lower than 3EMA 2 bar ago) or (Price for current bar's close lower than 3EMA 3 bar ago))

Your code shows the arrow for some of the events when this happens, but not for every time. How can that be done?

Comment: I think I don't even need m3=4 and m4=5 since those will refer to different EMAs than 3EMA

Comment: Define and plot all your elementary conditions separately to make sure they occur when you think they should. Once you've verified this, then simply assemble them in a single boolean expression with `and` between them. Use this technique: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-visualize-my-scripts-conditions-on-the-chart

Comment: ``//@version=4
study("EMA Trap", "EMA Trap", true)    
// EMA trap    
m1=8    
m2=3    
red=#FF0000    
tl=low    
tc=close    

em1 = ema(tl,m1)    
em2 = ema(tc,m1)    
em3 = ema(tc,m2)    

cond = (tl <= em1 and tc > em2) and (tc < em3[1] or tc < em3[1] or tc < em3[3])    
/// plotchar(cond, "cond", "▼", location.top)    
plotshape(cond, "cond", location=location.absolute, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.tiny, color=red, transp=0)``

Comment: That's work you need to do on your own. Follow the example in the FAQ and simply substitute your own conditions. If you can't code that yourself, then you'll need to hire someone to do that for you: https://www.pinecoders.com/resources/#trusted-pine-programmers-for-hire

Comment: So the above code was my attempt, but it looks like it works for some, but missed majority of the alerts/ conditions (red arrow). It also put alert where I wouldn't want to see the alert (black arrow)
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NyqAIoq1M35OdOEPI6r9aXlJbkTVe2Jl)